# when c++ standard introduces the suppose of the syntax `vector<vector<int>>` (i.e. `>>` in the end?

Tags: c++

```
include <vector>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<vector<int>> vecVecInts;

    return 0;
}
```

I have turned off Visual Studio 2008 language extension and compiled the above code without warning or errors.

I used to remember that we have to replace the following line

```
vector<vector<int>>
```

with

```
vector<vector<int> >
```

because the compiler at that time doesn't recognize the `>>` in the end.

**Question**> When does C++ standard introduce this syntax sweeter?

Thank you

Comment: I *think* this question suits [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was introduced in the most recent standard, C++11, §14.2/3:

> When parsing a template-argument-list, the first non-nested `>` is taken as the ending delimiter
>   rather than a greater-than operator. Similarly, the first non-nested `>>` is treated as two consecutive but
>   distinct `>` tokens, the first of which is taken as the end of the template-argument-list and completes the
>   template-id.

Comment: This is exactly what I understand. However, why C++2008 supports this when I turned off the language extension. Project Property Pages/C/C++/Language/Disable Language Extensions

Comment: @q0987: VC++ 2008 includes some bits and pieces of C++11. Given that this was known to be a part of the new standard when it was written, they may not have thought of it as an extension.